# How to make node js api synchronous to fire mongodb's multiple queries?

Tags: node.js

I have an api in node.js which find the id of category by its name and when the result comes it send this id in another function and calls for all of its parent categories id.If there is no any parent category then in array it should be added and if there is parent category then it should also be added in array.My problem is that the response is send an blank array just because of asynchronous call.How to make this synchronous through async-waterfall ?please help me .Thank you in advance

```
    router.post('/api/getproductofcategory', function(req, res) {
      var name = req.body.category;
      var cidarray = [];

      Category.getCategoryIdByname(name, function(err, categoryId) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

        if (categoryId.length) {
          console.log(categoryId);
          Category.getcategoryWithSameParentFun(categoryId[0]._id, function(
            err,
            categoryWithSameParent
          ) {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            } else {
              console.log(categoryWithSameParent);
              if (categoryWithSameParent.length == 0) {
                cidarray.push(categoryId[0]._id);
              } else {
                cidarray.push(categoryWithSameParent._id);
              }

Product.getProductByCategoryid(cidarray[0], function(err, products){
                if(err){
                    console.log('error', err);
                }
                else{
                    console.log(products);
                            } 

            })
}
          });
        }
      });

      res.end('result', cidarray);
    });
```

Comment: Basically I see no loop there. so moving `res.end(...)` inside of `Category.getcategoryWithSameParentFun()`'s callback seems to be enough.

Comment: I had updated my code above.here when cidarray have multiple cid's then my product function will run for multiple time.for  this i have to use async-waterfall and send all products in response.

Comment: What does `Product.getProductByCategoryid` do to `cidarray`?

Comment: from cid array it one by one take all the ids and send the request to productquery one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I changed variable names a bit and made some comments. I don't really know why you want to send `cidarray` as a API response but anyway this is how you basically control your flow with [`async/each`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each).

```
const each = require('async/each');

router.post('/api/getproductofcategory', function(req, res) {
  var name = req.body.category;
  var cidarray = [];

  Category.getCategoryIdByname(name, function(err, categoryIds) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    each(
      categoryIds,
      function(categoryId, callback) {
        Category.getcategoryWithSameParentFun(categoryId._id, function(
          err,
          categoryWithSameParent
        ) {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          } else {
            if (categoryWithSameParent.length == 0) {
              cidarray.push(categoryId[0]._id);
            } else {
              cidarray.push(categoryWithSameParent._id);
            }
            callback();
          }
        });
      },
      function(err) {
        // Here your cid array is filled with desired values.

        each(
          cidarray,
          function(cid, callback) {
            Product.getProductByCategoryid(cid, function(err, products) {
              if (err) {
                console.log('error', err);
              } else {
                // Don't know exactly what you're trying to do with products here.
                // Whatever it is you should call callback() after you do your job with each cid.
                console.log(products);
              }
            });
          },
          function(err) {
            // Final step. You end your response here.
            res.end('result', cidarray);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: No,I want to send products as my response

Comment: @Amansharma Then you declare products variable and push products at console.log(products).